# SWT: show popup menu below toolbar button after clicking on it

Tags: swt, toolbar, popupmenu

I want to show a popup *menu* below a toolbar button when the user clicks this button. I've read about the `SWT.DROP_DOWN` style for a `ToolItem` but this seems very much limited to a simple list of items according to [this sample](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/WorkingwithDropdowns.htm). Instead, I want to show a popup menu with, e.g., checkbox and radio button menu items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make MenuItem with styles SWT.CHECK, SWT.CASCADE, SWT.PUSH, SWT.RADIO, SWT.SEPARATOR
[see javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/package-summary.html)..

So you can "hang" swt menu to selection of dropdown on toolbar item like this

```
public class Test {

private Shell shell;

public Test() {
    Display display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setSize(50, 100);

    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT);
    ToolItem itemDrop = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    itemDrop.setText("drop menu");

    itemDrop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        Menu dropMenu = null;

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if(dropMenu == null) {
                dropMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
                shell.setMenu(dropMenu);
                MenuItem itemCheck = new MenuItem(dropMenu, SWT.CHECK);
                itemCheck.setText("checkbox");
                MenuItem itemRadio = new MenuItem(dropMenu, SWT.RADIO);
                itemRadio.setText("radio1");
                MenuItem itemRadio2 = new MenuItem(dropMenu, SWT.RADIO);
                itemRadio2.setText("radio2");
            }

            if (e.detail == SWT.ARROW) {
                // Position the menu below and vertically aligned with the the drop down tool button.
                final ToolItem toolItem = (ToolItem) e.widget;
                final ToolBar  toolBar = toolItem.getParent();

                Point point = toolBar.toDisplay(new Point(e.x, e.y));
                dropMenu.setLocation(point.x, point.y);
                dropMenu.setVisible(true);
            } 

        }

    });

    shell.open();

    while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }

    display.dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

}
```

Comment: BTW, is it possible for `SWT.DROP_DOWN` toolbar buttons to distinguish between clicks on the normal button (which should directly invoke an action) and clicking the drop-down-area (which should show the drop down menu)?

Comment: Yes it is. The `SelectionEvent e` which you get as parameter of listener method have attribute `e.detail` which is `0` if the button is pushed and `4` (which is value of `SWT.ARROW`) if the arrow is pressed.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `setLocation()` method can also accept a `Point`, making it possible to do `dropMenu.setLocation(toolBar.toDisplay(new Point(e.x, e.y)));`, if you're into that kind of one-line programming.